# Does the order matter while writing a Conversion Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I have two eigen vectors \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0  \end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\2  \end{pmatrix}. So will the eigen basis be  \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix} or \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
2 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} ?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it matters in that sense, when you use the matrix with your eigenvectors as the columns, when performing a linear transformation, a vector needs to be expressed in terms of the vectors that make up the basis (Change of basis). When you switch the columns of your matrix, the "order" of the basis elements need to be switched accordingly.

Comment: What do you want to ultimately do?

Comment: Please take more care when posing a question. Issues here are: (1) it is not very clear what you are after here (2) matrices and bases are different things, (3) "the eigen basis" is not really a thing. There is a notion of "basis of eigenvectors", which may or may not exist, but if it does it is almost never unique, so "the" is not warranted. And yes, you can figure out yourself that given that those vectors are eigenvectors, both proposed "bases" are indeed basses of eigenvectors. (4) eigenvectors are relative to some linear operator, which is not even mentioned here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is the original matrix whose eigenvectors you computed. Suppose that 
$\xi_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, while 
$\xi_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}
$ correpsonds to the eigenvalue $\lambda_2$. Define the following matrices:
\begin{equation}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad
Q= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

The difference between $P$ and $Q$ is the effect they have on the diagonal representations of $A$:
\begin{equation}
P^{-1} A P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{whereas} \quad
Q^{-1}AQ = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

So, the answer to your question is: it depends on what you mean by "matter". If you mean "does it make a difference", then the answer is yes, because as I mentioned above, the eigenvalues will be swapped in the diagonal representation of $A$. But, if you mean "is there any inherent reason to choose one over the other?" the answer is no; you just need to be aware of where the eigenvalues go.

---

Added Remark:

Just a comment about your terminology: you said "will the eigen basis be ...", but then you proceed to list the matrices $P$ and $Q$ I defined. I hope you know that $P$, $Q$ are called the "change of basis/coordinate matrix", whereas the eigenbasis is the basis of eigenvectors: $\{\xi_1, \xi_2\}$.

If you want to be more specific, you could speak of the "ordered eigenbasis" $\{\xi_1, \xi_2\}$ and $\{\xi_2, \xi_1\}$, to emphasise that you want to keep track of the order.

I only brought this up for your knowledge, if you just happened to be a little imprecise and you know the distinction, then of course ignore this remark.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the eigenvectors doesn’t matter per se. However, there might be other constraints in play. For instance, it’s common for the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix to be arranged in either descending or ascending order. In that case, the eigenvectors must be arranged to match.